# JSON management / user interface programs?

Tags: json, user-interface, converters

I just downloaded a large json file (about 3m KB) and I'd love advice on the best GUI interface to examine the data and create exports to CSV for further processing in GIS/QGIS. I know Apachi has some of these features -- but I've never done this particularly kind of processing. Any suggestions for open / free software? Thank you!

Comment: I was tempted to edit "(about 3m KB)" to say "(about 3KB)", but it occurred to me that I don't actually know what you mean: 3,000,000 KB? 3 KB?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what "3m KB" means, but for reasonable-sized JSON data, I use jsonviewer.stack.hu to good effect.